# How do you write a value into a cell inside a table, using row/column values?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working with VBA for only a couple hours now :).
I am creating a workout tracker. I have a table that is already populated, but I want to update a couple of the cells at the push of a button. Most of the posts I've found on here deal with adding new rows/columns, but that's not what I'm looking to do.

I tried something along the lines of...

```
tbl = Sheets("Workouts").ListObjects("tbl_Workouts")

tbl.Offset(TodaysRow,FirstExerciseCol + 5*ColCount).Value = NewValue
```

Obvious to you all, this syntax is not allowed.

Basically, if I want to write a value to the x row, y column of this table, how to I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ListObject` doesn't have an `Offset` property; a `Range` does.

---

Perhaps use the [`DataBodyRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.databodyrange), which

> returns a `Range` object that represents the range of values, excluding the header row, in a table.

An example that writes to the `x` row and `y` column of the table (without using `Offset`):

```
Sub TestMyTable()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Sheets("Workouts").ListObjects("tbl_Workouts")

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    x = 1
    y = 1

    tbl.DataBodyRange(x, y).Value = 1 ' or tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, y)
End Sub
```